# Ebay Finding API and C#

Tags: c#, ebay-api

Before I go off and write my own, is there already a nice C# wrapper for the [Ebay Finding API](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/Concepts/FindingAPIGuide.html) out there?

Comment: eBay officially produced one, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13214253/75500)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are not a lot of wrappers. Depending on what you need check out [LINQToEbay](http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoEbay). It might have what you need.

Comment: was wondering if you can help out wtih this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929259/ebay-api-returning-auctions-ending-later-than-10-days

Answer (score 1):

There is an official Finding API for .NET by eBay, check it out:

https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/finding-api

Download the zip file via [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/codebase/dotnetsdk/FindingKitDotNet_1.0.zip).